# Странное поведение make с wildcard

Tags: makefile

Есть вот такой makefile

```
OUTPUT=./aaa
FILE=./test.txt

all: prepare deploy check

prepare:
    mkdir -p ${OUTPUT}
    echo "test" > ${FILE}

deploy:
    cp ${FILE} ${OUTPUT}

check:
ifeq (${OUTPUT}/${FILE},$(wildcard ${OUTPUT}/${FILE}))
    echo YES
else
    echo NO
endif
```

Запускаю 2 раза подряд - результат разный

```
[/tmp/1]# make
mkdir -p ./aaa
echo "test" > ./test.txt
cp ./test.txt ./aaa
echo NO
NO
[/tmp/1]# make
mkdir -p ./aaa
echo "test" > ./test.txt
cp ./test.txt ./aaa
echo YES
YES
[/tmp/1]#


[/tmp/1]# make --version
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: «первый раз» — после чего?

Comment: не воспроизводится. потому и спрашиваю — как вы «первый раз» отличаете от «второго», «третьего» и так далее. составьте, пожалуйста, [mcve](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), указав заодно и версию программы *make*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin отличаю по очередности запуска. :) Обновил вопрос

Comment: теперь понятней. «первый раз» отличается от «второго» отсутствием файла. это [следствие оптимизации](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41470676/4827341) ([ещё](https://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/trouble-wildcard)) (ещё это подробно разобрано в «[gnu make book](https://nostarch.com/gnumake)»).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin печально. Спасибо.